# How can we fetch top 3 data value from database

Tags: sqlite

There is three field in my data base id(primary key),name, salary
I want fetch top 3 salary from the database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite - sorting a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669964/sqlite-sorting-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LIMIT to get top 3 after ordering, as such:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY id DESC;`

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT [column(s)]
      FROM [table]
  ORDER BY [column(s)] [ASC, DESC];
```

For more information check here:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Answer (score 1):

SQL has an [ORDER BY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) clause that allows you do order the result set by any column/columns, ascending and descending.

For your particular question:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM myTable
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669964/sqlite-sorting-a-table) SO question (SQLite - sorting a table).