# sort names in alphabitical order in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list of names in Mysql Database and i want to sort them according to the first alphabet.

When i run this code i get the sentence in the Quotes printed out

```
import sqlite3
import csv
conn = sqlite3.connect('RefinedDatabase.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
selectRow = cursor.execute( "SELECT Lecturer FROM staffDataBase")
fetchrow = cursor.fetchone()
while fetchrow != None:
    fetchrow =  str(fetchrow).replace(',)','').replace('(','').replace('u\'','').replace("'","").replace('u"', '').replace('"','')
    fetchrow = 'SELECT lecturer  FROM staffDataBase ORDER BY lecturer'
    print fetchrow
    fetchrow = cursor.fetchone()
conn.close() 
print ("All Done!!")
```

Comment: _sentence in the quotes printed out_ . Are you only getting `All Done!` ?

Comment: No im getting ' SELECT lecturer FROM staffDataBAse Order By lecturer' printed 50 times as i have 50 names to sort.

Comment: Because you are printing your `fetchrow` which is nothing but a string. That print statement is executed for every matching record in your database.

Comment: If i change the code to: 
while fetchrow != None:

 fetchrow =  str(fetchrow).replace(',)','').replace('(','').replace('u\'','').replace("'","").replace('u"', '').replace('"','')
 fetchrow = cursor.execute("SELECT lecturer  FROM staffDataBase ORDER BY lecturer")
 print fetchrow
 fetchrow = cursor.fetchone()  ... This just prints the ongoing memory address as : <sqlite3.cursor object at 0x0000000002065810>

Comment: Why are you modifying your query with `.replace`? Did you look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) ?

Comment: when i extract information from MySQL it prints out with extra parenthesis around each field. i want to replace all of them with nothing.

Comment: Could you paste that here? I think I know what your problem is

Comment: It prints out something like (u'2006-01-05', u'BUY', u'RHAT', 100, 35.14)
(u'2006-03-28', u'BUY', u'IBM', 1000, 45.0)
(u'2006-04-06', u'SELL', u'IBM', 500, 53.0)
(u'2006-04-05', u'BUY', u'MSFT', 1000, 72.0) .... from the docs you attached .... I cant post any pictures caz im new to this and the browser wont let me:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks ORDER BY price'):
        print row
```

will give you

```
(u'2006-01-05', u'BUY', u'RHAT', 100, 35.14)
(u'2006-03-28', u'BUY', u'IBM', 1000, 45.0)
(u'2006-04-06', u'SELL', u'IBM', 500, 53.0)
(u'2006-04-05', u'BUY', u'MSFT', 1000, 72.0)
```

Here `row` is nothing but a tuple and python allows you to unpack a tuple.

You can do this:

```
numbers = []
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks ORDER BY price'):
            date, process,company,number,rate = row
            numbers.append(number)

numbers.sort()
print numbers
```

Output:

```
[100, 500, 1000, 1000]
```

If you want to update the table with the sorted tuples you can do this instead:

```
from operator import itemgetter

tup = ((u'2006-01-05', u'BUY', u'RHAT', 100, 35.14),(u'2006-03-28', u'BUY', u'IBM', 1000, 45.0), (u'2006-04-06', u'SELL', u'IBM', 500, 53.0), (u'2006-04-05', u'BUY', u'MSFT', 1000, 72.0))
sorted_tup = tuple(sorted(tup, key=itemgetter(3)))

print sorted_tup
```

And then follow the steps listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17187017/1664675) answer

Comment: Thank You :) .. its actually working with a print statement but not updating the database.

Comment: If you are doing a `SELECT` on your database it will only return the tuples that match your query. I dont exactly know what you mean by updating here

Comment: i want to update this sorted information back into MySql database.

Comment: Rows in relational databases have no inherent order. A table is a *bag* of rows, not an array. So updating the table "in sorted order" isn't a thing.