# SQL query for a single (uniformly random) float value when duplicate floats may exist

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Given a table with a float field that is indexed (and allows duplicates) I assume I can query a row based on the next nearest floating point value using:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_float_column > 0.1234 ORDER BY my_float_column LIMIT 1
```

I want to query a random row from this table uniformly in the range `[0, 1]`, to do so I propose generating a uniformly random float and substituting it into the query above.

Conceptually this seems like it should work (correct me if I didn't think of something), except for the edge case when multiple identical values exist. `0.5` is one such case, in the database there's a large concentration of identical `0.5` float values.

When I query the database using a randomly chosen float I will get `0.5` with uniform probability (biased some by any gap between `0.5` and the next smallest float, but let's ignore that detail) however when I do randomly select `0.5` values I want to randomly choose **any of the rows** that take on the exact value of `0.5`.

Is there a better solution to querying in a random uniform way? Or is there a solution to ensure I get a random row with the `LIMIT 1` under these conditions?

Comment: Something in me is screaming that this absolutely, definitively, is not random. In virtually every case in SQLite, I think the query returns in relation to the insertion order. I cannot substantiate the claim properly but I really think this isn't the way. Is the data too big to hold in memory?

Comment: In the case of duplicate values, such as the `0.5` example, the query above would return a deterministic row, not random, which is the core issue. Assuming the table is large, I don't want to return all values above `0.5`. One solution could be to query the range `[0.5, 0.5 + epsilon]` and then choose randomly, from all `0.5` values returned, but that's not very elegant in cases where there are many matching values.

Comment: @roganjosh Without an `ORDER BY`, rows are returned in arbitrary undefined order that in practice depends on things like if covering indexes are used ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56096228/sql-query-returns-values-when-selecting-multiple-columns-but-no-data-when-selec/56096942#56096942)), window functions, what table is first in a join, etc.

Comment: Forgetting to add ORDER BY was just an oversight in writing the question, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want equality, you will need equality:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_float_column >= 0.1234
LIMIT 1
```

Otherwise, you can never get `0.5` if you pass in `0.5`.  Also note that floating point representations might be tricky for comparisons.  0.5 has an exact representation, but most other values are approximations, which can cause problems for equality comparisons . . . but I'm going to ignore that.

Floating point values also do not do a good job with representing a uniform distribution.  There are way more floating point numbers (as represented in the data type) between 0 and 0.00001 than between 0.99999 and 1.00000.  Fixed point numerics might be a better representation in such a range.

And all that said, what your question is really about is randomness for equal values.  First, your method is flawed, because you are just returning any value bigger than what you want.  This is more correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_float_column >= 0.1234
ORDER BY my_float_column DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And, to get randomness, use `rand()` as a second key:

```
ORDER BY my_float_column, rand()
```

For performance, I would recommend an index on `my_float_column`.  The `rand()` is a performance killer because it prevents use of the index, but you can modify the query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
WHERE t.my_float_column >= 0.1234 AND
      t.my_float_column <= (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(t2.my_float_column), t.my_float_column))
                            FROM my_table t2
                            WHERE t2.my_float_column > 0.1234
                           )
ORDER BY my_float_column DESC, rand()
LIMIT 1;
```